# How to Put an integer value into an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

Suppose I have to store indexpath.row values(i.e indexes) of table cells into an array. How can i achive that?

**Please explain with a code snippet**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray (and other objective-c containers) stores objects, so you'll need to create NSNumber object to store it in array:

```
NSNumber *num  = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
[yourMutableArray addObject:num];
```

Also have a look at NSIndexSet(NSMutableIndexSet) classes - may be they will serve your purpose better

Comment: And also you can obtain stored index like int value = [[yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue];

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the NSIndexPath in the array.

Answer (score 0):

what array you mean?
you can create in your h. : NSInteger arr[10]; // make an array size 10

and then fill it with your values: 
for (int i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) {arr[i] = 1}
for example..